# Find solution to the differential equation

Tags: integration, derivatives, differential

$\frac{dB}{dx}+2B=50$

$B(1) = 50$

I tried separating the variables but that didn't work, and without separating the variable I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: I would suggest reading through this: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx

This will help you learn how to solve equations of this form

Comment: you will have $$
\begin{array}{c} B(x)=e^{-2 x} c_1+25 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Thanks for editing my LaTex formatting Eric, and thanks for the article Brenton, I'll make sure to check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

separating the variable works:

$$
\frac {dB}{dx}  = 50 - 2B
\\
\int \frac{dB}{25 - B} = \int 2dx + C, C\in\Bbb R \\
-\log |25 - B| = 2x + C, C\in\Bbb R
$$
yields the general solution:
$$
B = 25 + K\exp (-2x), K\in\Bbb R
$$
and with the initial condition:
$$
B = 25 (1+ \exp (2(1-x)))
$$

Comment: Ah, I was subtracting the right side rather than dividing, that makes much mores sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this O.D.E as follows
$$\frac{dB}{dx}+2B=0$$
$$m+2=0$$
$$m=-2$$
$$y_c=C_1e^{-2x}$$
to find the particular solution
$$y_p=A$$
then the $A=25$
hence
$$y=C_1e^{-2x}+25$$